# SharePoint 2013 list make the header drop down arrow always visible

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

as you know, there is a drop down arrow in each SharePoint list column, which provides nice filter capability and you can do a multiple value selections;however, the drawback is that the arrow icon is only shown when mouseover it. don't know what the logic behind but I feel it is not intuitive at all, as such i want to add a CSS code to make the arrow always visible. Initially i added the following snippet:

```
.ms-headerSortArrowLink {
    display: inline-block!important;
}
```

it doesn't work, so i checked the code element. I don't know why I cannot style the class ".ms-headerSortArrowLink", and when i changed the inline  to , the arrow icon becomes visible in one column but still hidden in the rest. 
Would you please help me how to make the arrow icon always visible? In addition, what I can do if i want to replace the existing arrow icon? I saw the image source is "src="/_layouts/15/images/ecbarw.png?rev=23", but i don't know how to replace it. 
 thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the CSS below into script editor web part to achieve it.

```
<style type="text/css">
.s4-ctx{
    margin: 0px; top: -21.73px; height: 29px; right: -17px; line-height: 27px;
}
.s4-ctx img {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css styles:

```
.s4-ctx img {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

And after DOMContentLoaded js code:

```
$("[scope='col']").each(function(){
    OnChildColumn(this);
    $(".ms-vh2").removeClass("ms-headerCellStyleHover");
})
```

Comment: Sir, I tried but didn't get any luck ... the arrow icon disappeared even mouseover the column header after I added the JS code.

Comment: Without js code, css helps to show arrow? Do you use SP 2013 on-prem?

Comment: After added the CSS snippet, the arrow icon is visible but the position is not correct.

Comment: I'm using 2013 on-premise

Comment: And if you manually execute the js code after page loaded in console is it helps with position?

Comment: I didn't get any luck. the arrow shows under the column name instead of next to it ... but when hovering over the column, the location of the arrow is immediately changed to the next to the column name